# Replacing an id (integer) with a string?

Tags: macros, strings

I have a tex document that contains sections that are automatically generated.  These sections have strings that are observation IDs.  I would like to have latex replace all occurrences of an ID with a string containing the star's name.

For example:

```
\caption{SED of \OID1342263516}
```

Would become:

```
\caption{SED of FR Tau}
```

My first thought was to have a macro, something like this:

```
\newcommand{\OID1342263516}{FR Tau}
```

However, I have learned that macros can't have numbers in their name.  Is there a good way to go about doing what I want?  Thanks.

Comment: I've got a solution I think, gimme 5 minutes :-)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It would be ***much*** easier if the generated code was `\OID{1342263516}`

Comment: @egreg Indeed, that's why it took me 3 minutes too long :-)

Comment: What is an OID? The number in star catalogue?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, essentially.  In this case it's the observation ID used by ESAs Herschel Telescope.

Comment: @equant: I hope, the Herschel did not observe more than `10^12` stars then ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's with a bit of plain e-TeX to make it without the extra braces. The maximal value allowed here is `1073741823000`, the minimal one is `1000` (or less if you make it at least 4 digits, I hope you fit in that. In can be extended by *x* digits, but only in case that all your numbers have at least *x* digits.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\OIDcounta
\newcount\OIDcountb
\def\useOID{\csname OID\the\OIDcounta\the\OIDcountb\endcsname}
\protected\def\OID#1#2#3{\OIDcounta#1#2#3\afterassignment\useOID\OIDcountb}
\def\newOID#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname OID#1\endcsname{#2}}

\newOID{123456}{Tau 456 epsilon}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{ABC \OID123456\ DEF}

Star number hundred twenty three is \OID123456\ for sure.

\typeout{\number\maxdimen}

\end{document}
```

If you're fine with the braces, then it's easy, and will work for even very large numbers (tens of digits):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\OID#1{\@ifundefined{OID#1}{\GenericError{}{OID#1 not defined!}{}{}}{\csname OID#1\endcsname}}
\def\newOID#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname OID#1\endcsname{#2}}
\makeatother

\newOID{123456}{Tau 456 epsilon}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{ABC \OID{123456} DEF}

Star number hundred twenty three is \OID{123456} for sure.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, fast.  Thanks.  So if \OID{1342263516} is easier as suggested by egreg, could you show me how that method would look?

Comment: Actually, the number 1342263516 is larger than 1073741823 and the macro still works. But there's no guarantee when the  number is much larger.

Comment: @egreg I shoved off the first 3 digits now, so it works for anything from `1000` to a lot.

Comment: @equant Here you go.

Comment: Perfect.  Both methods worked perfectly for me.  The later is definitely easier to read.  Thanks!

Comment: @equant Not only that, it's also quite fool-proof. The first one is a very very very very dirty trick :-D